# Parsing files (ics/ Vcalendar) using Python

Tags: python

I have a .ics file in the following format. What is the best way to parse it. I need to retrieve the Summary, Description, and Time for each of the entries. Thanks in advance for your help.

**January 31th 8pm : ,
2011 Cricket 
match at chennai

Comment: it looks not like a complete '.ics' file.

Answer (score 5):

Look at [icalendar](https://github.com/collective/icalendar) or [vobject](http://vobject.skyhouseconsulting.com/).